# How to speed up mm in module making of AOSP

Tags: android, compilation, makefile, android-source

I am working on the contacts app from android open source project. My android version is 2.3.5_r1. And using mm to make the module, but the making speed is quite slow, so i doubt if there is a method to speed up the making.

PS:Actually if i compile this module in eclipse, i will speed up a litter because the auto build feature of eclipse. But i don't like work with eclipse so give it up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order of least cost to you:

- Don't make clean so much. Allow the makefile to determine what to rebuild.
- Use CCACHE `export USE_CCACHE=1`. You're only likely to see the effects of CCACHE upon having rebuilt multiple times. If your project is large set a higher CCACHE size e.g. 10GB `${ANDROID_DIR}/prebuilt/linux-x86/ccache/ccache -M 10G`
- Get a better processor and run with higher -j parameter

Comment: You have almost list every method to speed up building. Thanks aultbot.

Comment: I would add get more RAM 8 - 24GB if you wanted to speed up re-building the whole AOSP and not just a single project. You need a CCACHE 10 - 100GB for that too (towards 100 for rebuilding all configs)

Comment: How much time does it cost to build entire AOSP by your computer.

Comment: Under half an hour for a specific target with -j8.
Processor = i5-2500K, 8 GB RAM

Comment: For my computer it costs two to three hours T_T.

Answer (score 6):

For instance, I use the following command from the root folder of your Android project:

```
mmm frameworks/base snod -j4
```

And I think that this is the best choice. Try it but substitute `frameworks/base` with your project name (relative path where Android.mk is stored).

Comment: And set CCACHE=1 to enable cache can also used to speed up building.

Comment: It is doubtful because CCACHE reserve a lot of space on the computer and if you just build one your project I do not see any reasonable speed improvement with this parameter enabled.

Comment: This should be a) the accepted answer b) on AOSP guide.

Answer (score 2):

### 1. Build module + dependencies

`mmma` is slower than `mmm`, as the former make sure all dependencies are met for the module, and if they are not it compiles them as well. So, initially instead of a full `make` command, build the dependencies concerning the module you are interested in using the following:

```
mmma -j4 adir/yourmoduledir
```

### 2. Build module

Now that dependencies have met, keep recompiling just the module you are interested in. Skipping check for dependencies saves precious time. The directory you are using though, might contain more than one compilation target. To compile a single target, use something like:

```
mmm -j4 adir/yourmoduledir:moduletargetname
```

## Example

#### Build libart

Build  library and all of its dependencies **once**:

```
mmma -j4 art/runtime
```

Modify libart's code and quickly build it:

```
mmm -j4 art/runtime:libart
```

You will get half compilation time in comparison to Yury's approach as for example the debugging flavor of `libart` (`libartd`) will be omitted altogether.

## Further speedup?

You should of course enable caching as suggested by `aultbot`.

Also, depending on the modules you are interested, there might be compilation targets you might want to disable by digging up in the makefiles. For example `libart` is compiled for both the host and the target. If you modify a variable in the makefiles can force compilation just for one of the 2, saving you half of the time.

## Additional info:

- Checkout out the outdated build guide in aosp:
  [build/core/build-system.html](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+/master/core/build-system.html).
- N-Preview google is switching to a [new build system](https://github.com/google/kati) that aims to speed up incremental builds. I hope the documentation gets updated as well.

Answer (score 0):

I found that when I use my laptop ssh to my desktop computer and build module, I can build it very very fast. I don't know why.